# I'm getting CORS error: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: reactjs, express, cors

I have a Node/Express backend and React frontend. When I'm trying to send post request through axios from my react app to the backend, I get an error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:5000/api/user/create-account' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request
> header field content-type is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

But, `I'm using res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');` Still, I'm getting that error.

Here's the server side code:

```
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

let corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 ,
    credentials: true
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

And, this is how I'm making POST request from my frontend:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/user/create-account", data, { withCredentials: true } )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
  })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
  });
```

P.S: I know there are similar questions on here but I have followed their answers but my problem isn't solved that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: If this is for development only, you could up your CORS to any origin and have separate code for production. This stuff is a nightmare when it doesn't work and can be a real time drain, especially if you are trying to work around localhost, which can use proxies that complicate matters even more

Comment: have you tried with credentials: false? Not sure if that would help but I'm just throwing this out there.

Comment: @FujiRoyale yes. But, now I'm not getting any cookies.

Comment: @Doug Hill even if I just pass `app.use(cors())`, it doesn't work

Comment: Hi, this article saved hours for me. Please have a look https://medium.com/swlh/simple-steps-to-fix-cors-error-a2029f9b257a

Comment: @ZainJaved I haven't worked with Express, I have a .NET background, but this article says you can use an * to allow any. res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin, '*); https://www.positronx.io/express-cors-tutorial/